# How to split string in android

Tags: android, string, split

Suppose i have a String, below

```
String myText="I'm a android developer and i'm developing an android app";
```

so i want to split the above string with`(" ' "),` and want to put it on a textView so how it is possible. i have used this code

```
split(Pattern.quote("'"));
```

so my complete code is :

```
 textUser.setText(User);
        String[] newDesc=Description1.split(Pattern.quote("'"));
        for(String w:newDesc){
            textDesc.setText(w);
        }
```

but this is not working. Please resolve my issue

Comment: Simply you can do this as `String[] newDesc=Description1.split("'");`

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Pattern.quote()` wrapps your RegExp so that it only works if the matching string in inside quotes.

In other words, I do not believe in this case it would work.

A simple `String[] newDesc=Description1.split("'");` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this please

```
String[] newDesc=Description1.split("'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to understand the split string you need:

Example : `String myText = "I'm a android developer and i'm developing an android app";`

```
String[] strParts = myText.split("'");
```

Then

```
String strFirstString = strParts[0]; // I
String strSecondString = strParts[1]; // m a android developer and i
String strThirdString = strParts[2]; // m developing an android
```

Now display whichever String you want, in your textView.